# SVG image not displayed, possibly obscured

Tags: svg

I am an SVG novice. Is it obvious why the `image` is not visible?

```
<svg width="480" height="320" class="canvas">
  <g transform="translate(60,31.999999999999993)" width="372" height="248" class="main">
    <rect width="372" height="248" class="bgc8fcd31365f041fdba82105b45bba1541" fill="transparent"></rect>
    <g transform="translate(0,248)" class="axesc8fcd31365f041fdba82105b45bba1541 x axis">
      <g class="tick" transform="translate(338.1028735788505,0)" style="opacity: 1;">
        <line y2="6" x2="0"></line>
        <text y="9" x="0" dy=".71em" style="text-anchor: middle;">-200</text>
      </g>
      ... more like <g>...</g> above ...
      <path class="domain" d="M-6,0H0V248H-6"></path>
    </g>
    <clipPath id="clipc8fcd31365f041fdba82105b45bba1541">
      <rect x="0" y="0" width="372" height="248"></rect>
    </clipPath>
    <g clip-path="url(#clipc8fcd31365f041fdba82105b45bba1541)">
      <image x="0" y="0" width="300" height="300" src="data:image/png;base64,[redacted very long strict of data characters]"></image>
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

The image source is fine: using Chrome's Inspect Element feature, I can view it on its own in a separate tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [SVG `<image>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/SVG_Image_Tag) is slightly different from the [HTML one](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Img) as the attribute `src` is replaced by `xlink:href`.

So try the following code:

```
<image x="0" y="0" width="300" height="300" xlink:href="data:image/png;base64,[redacted very long strict of data characters]" />
```

with an accordingly defined `xlink` namespace.

```
xmlns:xlink= "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
```